# Python, how to not require an additional space at the end of the list?

Tags: python, algorithm, list

I've written a program which can compress a sequence of characters.

```
def compress(string):
    output = ""
    counter = 1
    firstLoop = True

    for element in range(0, len(string)):
        # if statement checking if current character was last character
        if string[element] == string[element - 1]:
            # if it was, then the character has been written more than one
            # time in a row, so increase counter
            counter = counter + 1
        else:
            # when we detect a new character reset the counter
            # and also record the character and how many times it was repeated
            if not firstLoop:
                output = output + string[element - 1] + str(counter)
        counter = 1

        firstLoop = False
    return output

data = "aaaabbbchhtttttttf"
print(data)

compressedData = compress(data)
print(compressedData)
```

The program outputs:

```
aaaabbbchhtttttttf
a4b3c1h2t7
```

So, it finds that there's '4' entries of 'a' so it writes 'a4', then 'b3' for three entries of b.

The issue is that it forgets about the 'f1' at the end of the string. I know this  is because of the line:

```
output = output + string[element - 1] + str(counter)
```

Since string[element-1] refers to the position in the string before the current element, thus, it will never reach the final position which is where 'f' is. The program doesn't work without the '-1' since it doesn't write the correct letter.

How can I get around this problem and make it able to include f?

The correct output should be a4b3c1h2t7f1.

Thanks :)

Edit: I forgot to mention that the program works if I include an additional character after the 'f', such as just a blank space. But that's of course because the final character in my string is just a space rather than a letter.

Comment: return output + string[-1] + str(counter). Also your counter = 1 should be inside the else

Comment: Thank you!! That works. And yeah it was inside the else, it didn't copy and paste properly @juvian

Answer (score 3):

You could do this all with [`itertools.groupby`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.groupby) and [`sum`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#sum) and avoid all counting and keeping track of indexes:

```
from itertools import groupby

def compress(string):
    return ''.join(k + str(sum(1 for _ in g)) for k, g in groupby(string))

>>> compress("aaaabbbchhtttttttf")
'a4b3c1h2t7f1'
```

Answer (score 2):

You could make it simpler and add a character at the end:

```
def compress(string):
    output = ""
    counter = 0
    string = string + '|'
    for element in range(0, len(string)):
        # if statement checking if current character was last character
        if string[element] == string[element - 1]:
            # if it was, then the character has been written more than one
            # time in a row, so increase counter
            counter = counter + 1
        elif element != len(string):
            output = output + string[element - 1] + str(counter)
            counter = 1
    return output[2:]

data = "aaaabbbchhtttttttf"
print(data)

compressedData = compress(data)
print(compressedData)
```

Comment: Running speed tests, this is slightly faster than the itertools solution, though I would argue the itertools solution is a really great pythonic way of doing it.

Comment: Yeah, this was my previous solution, thanks for the help

Answer (score 1):

```
def compress(string):
output = ""
counter = 1

for element in range(1, len(string)):
    # if statement checking if current character was last character
    if string[element] == string[element - 1]:
        # if it was, then the character has been written more than one
        # time in a row, so increase counter
        counter = counter + 1
    else:
        # when we detect a new character reset the counter
        # and also record the character and how many times it was repeated
        output = output + string[element - 1] + str(counter)
        counter = 1

return output + string[-1] + str(counter)
```

Also note that you need to start counting form `1` not `0` and get rid of `firstLoop`

Answer (score 0):

Try changing the loop to `for element in range(0, len(string) + 1)` and adding an extra if condition:

```
for element in range(0, len(string) + 1):
    if element == len(string):
        output = output + string[element-1] + str(counter)
    # if statement checking if current character was last character
    elif string[element] == string[element - 1]: ...
```

Answer (score 0):

In the spirit of fixing your code you just needed to simply add the element first to output before adding the counter on change. You can use a neat treat called `else` with for loops that will run at the end, which will add the final counter to `f`. No need to buffer or import anything special, you were fairly close:

```
def compress(string):
    output = ""
    counter = 0
    firstLoop = True

    for i in range(len(string)):
        # if statement checking if current character was last character
        if firstLoop:
            counter += 1
            output += string[i]
        else:
            if string[i] == string[i - 1]:
                counter += 1
            else:                
                output += str(counter) + string[i]
                counter = 1
        firstLoop = False      
    else:
        output += str(counter)
    return output

data = "aaaabbbchhtttttttf"
print(data)

compressedData = compress(data)
print(compressedData)
```